# Javascript issue: how to string replace double quotes with a backslash and a double quote

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I want to convert string `'"hello":1'` to `'\"hello\":1'`

Notice the single backslash in the output above? But none of the below snippets yields this result. It is either 2 backslashes or none at all

```
 var str = '"hello":1';
 str.replace(/"/g, '\"') => '"hello":1'
 str.replace(/"/g, '\\"') => '\\"hello\\":1'
 str.replace(/"/g, '\\\"') => '\\"hello\\":1'
```

Comment: In a string in JS, a backslash is the escape character. So for a backslash to be used it must also be escaped. `'\\'` is one backslash

Comment: The third solution is correct. The console is displaying the single backslash as two backslashes because it shows how you would have to type it.

Comment: True. I need only one backslash in the output which is actually to escape the double quote.